# SQL update value from previous row dynamically

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, common-table-expression, lag

I'm trying to update a value to equal the previous row's value within that `PrimaryID` group - but the previous row could also be updated based on my query. I can do it with a loop or cursor but for the few-million rows I'm dealing with, it just takes too long. I've used the `CTE` with `LAG` function described below but it's static and won't take into account values I've already updated.

```
declare @table table (PrimaryID int, SecondaryID int, Val decimal(10,2))
insert into @table values
(1,1,100),
(1,2,150),
(1,3,null),
(2,1,50),
(2,2,null),
(2,3,null),
(2,4,60),
(2,5,null),
(2,6,null)

;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT PrimaryID, SecondaryID, LAG(Val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY PrimaryID ORDER BY SecondaryID) previousVal FROM @table
)
UPDATE  t
SET     Val = cte.previousVal
FROM    @table t
JOIN    cte ON t.PrimaryID = cte.PrimaryID AND t.SecondaryID = cte.SecondaryID 
WHERE   t.SecondaryID > 1 
AND     t.Val IS NULL

select * from @table
```

initial data

| PrimaryID | SecondaryID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | *NULL* |
| 1 | 3 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 3 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 4 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 6 | *NULL* |

expected outcome

| Primary ID | Secondary ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | 50 |
| 2 | 4 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 6 | 60 |

actual outcome

| PrimaryID | SecondaryID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 1 | 50 |
| 2 | 2 | 50 |
| 2 | 3 | *NULL* |
| 2 | 4 | 60 |
| 2 | 5 | 60 |
| 2 | 6 | *NULL* |

Comment: You could do something like `COALESCE(LAG, 1),LAG(Val, 2),LAG(Val, 3))`

Comment: thank-you for your answer. my real data set has an unknown number of "lags", hundreds in some examples

Comment: in that case I don't see how you can do it without a subquery or a CTE, which will consume resources.

Comment: can it successfully be done with a cte? because I can't get it to recognize values I've already updated without using a cursor/loop

Comment: What version & year of sql server are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2017 - 14.0.3401.7

Answer (score 2):

use `APPLY` operator to find the last not null value to update back the table

```
UPDATE  t
SET     Val = v.Val
FROM    @table t
        CROSS APPLY
        (
             SELECT TOP 1 x.Val
             FROM   @table x
             WHERE  x.PrimaryID = t.PrimaryID
             AND    x.SecondaryID < t.SecondaryID
             AND    x.Val IS NOT NULL
             ORDER BY x.SecondaryID DESC
        ) v
WHERE   t.Val IS NULL
```